# formula in <list of values> for the command \foreach

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

good afternoon,
My computer was on Debian 10 (buster) and I could use the following Latex code :

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6]
%valeurs ci-dessous à changer en fonction du repère qu'on veut
\def\xmin{-3}
\def\xmax{3}
\def\ymin{-1}
\def\ymax{5}
\def\pasx{1} %pas des graduations en x
\def\pasy{1} %pas des graduations en y
\def\var{0.3}
\clip(\xmin-\var,\ymin-\var) rectangle(\xmax+\var,\ymax+\var);
%dessin des axes
\draw[->,thick](\xmin-\var,0)--(\xmax+\var,0);
\draw[->,thick](0,\ymin-\var)--(0,\ymax+\var);
%dessin de la grille
\draw[thin,dotted](\xmin-\var,\ymin-\var) grid[step=1] (\xmax+\var,\ymax+\var);
%axe des abscisses
\foreach \x in {\xmin,\xmin+\pasx,...,\xmax}\draw[thick](\x,0.1)--(\x,-0.1);
\foreach \x in {0,1}{
   \ifthenelse{\x=0}{\draw(\x-0.2,0)node[below=0.2]{\x};}{\draw(\x,0)node[below=0.2]{\x};}
}
%axe des ordonnées
\foreach \y in {\ymin,\ymin+\pasy,...,\ymax} \draw[thick](-0.1,\y)--(0.1,\y);
\foreach \y in {0,1}{
   \ifthenelse{\y=0}{}{\draw(0,\y)node[left=0.2]{\y};}
}
\draw (4,6) node[right]{$\mathscr{C}_f$};
\draw[domain=\xmin:\xmax,smooth,id=fig3] plot function{x**3-3*x+1};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Yesterday, I passed to Debian 11 and I can't compile anymore this code. The error is for
`\xmin+\pasx` and
`\ymin+\pasy` ...
Could somebody help me to understand what is the problem ? New version of tikz/pgf ?
It is a problem for me because I don't want to change each .tex files to solve this problem ...
Thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: Welcome! Did this really work in the past? You need to evaluate the second value before the `...` magic can properly work with it, unfortunately. Or you construct the loop differently, say `\foreach[parse=true]\x in {0, \pasx, ..., (\xmax-\xmin)} \draw[thick](\xmin+\x), .1) -- +(down:.2);`.

Comment: ok thanks. I have installed Texlive with the offical .deb package from Debian 10 and the code was correct. But, with Debian 11 no. I tried to install the official TexLive, not by Debian, and it is the same problem. A friend have installed the last version of Ubuntu recently and my code is ok for him .. ???

Comment: Something changed between texlive 2018 to 2019 in tikz/pgf. You will have to adapt your code. E.g. `\fpeval{\xmin+\pasx}` in the foreach loop will work too.